# Adding condition to custom tab product detail page

Tags: configurable-product, customer, layout

I added custom tabs to product detail page. Below is my code:

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.new.tab" as="new.tab" template="catalog/product/view/mynewcustomtab.phtml">
    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
    <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Stock Details</value></action>
</block>
```

I have added this code into `catalog.xml`

My problem is that

1. I want to add condition that it will show only if user type is `wholeseller`
2. I want to show if only for configurable products?

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways, like adding a simple if else statement retrieving the users customer group but Atwix has a nice [post about adding customer group layout handles](http://www.atwix.com/magento/magento-customer-group-layout-handle/) which I would recommend to follow after which, in your `local.xml` you can add

```
<customer_group_wholesale>
   <reference name="product.info">
      <block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.new.tab" as="new.tab" template="catalog/product/view/mynewcustomtab.phtml">
         <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
         <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Stock Details</value></action>
      </block>
   </reference>
</customer_group_wholesale>
```

Comment: Very good intro into adding custom layout handles but how could you link this and product type :)

Answer (score 1):

So to show this block for only configurable products you can use the product type based layout handle `PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable`. Now your code should look like the following.

```
<PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.new.tab" as="new.tab" template="catalog/product/view/mynewcustomtab.phtml">
            <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
            <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Stock Details</value></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</PRODUCT_TYPE_configurable>
```